# Issue with getting column names

Tags: r, list, data.table, names

I have a table like below.`(Table1)`

```
Table1:

Type   Fund   Con_counts
5510   COM    1
5520   COM    2
0300   COM    2
5510   COM    1
.
```

and use the following

```
Table1 <- Table1[, list(Con_counts = sum(as.double(Con_counts), na.rm = TRUE)), by = list(Type, Fund)]
```

How can I get the column names separeted by comma (,) using a code so that I can place within () brackets.

For example, I tried the my code below and does not work.

```
columns <- colnames(Table2)[!(names(Table2) %in% c("Con_counts"))]

Table1[, list(Con_counts = sum(as.double(Con_counts), na.rm = TRUE)), by = list(columns)]
```

columns should be `Type,Fund`

```
Output: 
    Type   Fund   Con_counts
    5510   COM    2
    5520   COM    2
    0300   COM    2
```

Comment: Did you try `by=columns` without wrapping in `list(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this answer has been asked before but I have not found a good duplicate.

This is what I would do in `data.table` syntax using the `setdiff()` function:

```
columns <- setdiff(names(Table1), c("Con_counts"))
Table1[, .(Con_counts = sum(as.double(Con_counts), na.rm = TRUE)), by = columns]
```

> ```
>    Type Fund Con_counts
> 1: 5510  COM          2
> 2: 5520  COM          2
> 3:  300  COM          2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
Table1 <- fread(
"  Type   Fund   Con_counts
5510   COM    1
5520   COM    2
0300   COM    2
5510   COM    1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Table1 <- data.frame(Type = c(5510,5520,0300,5510),
                     Fund = c('COM','COM','COM','COM'),
                     Con_counts = c(1,2,2,1))

Table1 %>%
     group_by(Type,Fund) %>%
     summarise(Con_counts = sum(Con_counts)) %>%

   Type Fund  Con_counts
  <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1  300. COM           2.
2 5510. COM           2.
3 5520. COM           2.
```

If you still want to use `data.tables`, I can't help you with that, but the answer below can help you get your column names:

To get the column names of `Table1`, just use `colnames(Table1)` which returns a character vector.

```
columns <- colnames(Table1)
columns
[1] 'Type'   'Fund'   'Con_counts'
```

If you want to remove 'Con_counts from that list, there are several options:

```
# If you know that 'Con_counts' is the 3rd column,
#   you can call colnames on a sliced version of the data frame
colnames(Table1[,-3])
[1] 'Type'   'Fund'

colnames(Table1[,c(-2,-3)])
[1] 'Type'


# If you want to drop by name
columns <- colnames(Table1)
columns[columns != 'Con_counts']
[1] 'Type'   'Fund'

# If you want to drop by multiple names
columns[!(columns %in% c('Con_counts', 'Type'))]
[1] 'Fund'
```

You can select those columns by inserting that variable into bracket notation.

```
Table[1, columns]
# Type   Fund   Con_counts
# 5510   COM    1
```